# Quickbooks Online Edition - Push data from website to display in quickbook online and Fetching data from quick book online to display on website

Tags: php, quickbooks-online, qbxml

I am using keith palmer's PHP devkit push data to quick book online essential account with QBXML.

I have created QBOE app in "PRODUCTION" mode and successfully get app id, app login and connection ticket.But I am stuck in QBXML. It will respond me blank.

After calling this,

```
$resp = $Gateway->qbxml($xml);
print($Gateway->lastRequest());
print($Gateway->lastResponse());
```

My out put is as below, but doesn't pull any data in quick book online essential account.

```
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonDesktopRq>
            <ClientDateTime>2013-10-04T12:49:04</ClientDateTime>
            <ApplicationLogin>********************</ApplicationLogin>
            <ConnectionTicket>********************</ConnectionTicket>
            <Language>English</Language>
            <AppID>************</AppID>
            <AppVer>1</AppVer>
        </SignonDesktopRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>
</QBXML>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 06:13:21 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8r ApacheJServ/1.1.2
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC "-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBO 6.0//EN" "http://apps.quickbooks.com/dtds/qbxmlops60.dtd">
<QBXML>
<SignonMsgsRs>
  <SignonDesktopRs statusCode="2000" statusMessage="Application agent not found **************" statusSeverity="ERROR">
   <ServerDateTime>2013-10-04T06:13:47</ServerDateTime>
  </SignonDesktopRs>
</SignonMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Need some help. If any one have an idea what is going wrong.?

For adding Sales Order to quick book online essential account from my website I am using qbxml from this URL, "http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Adding_a_Sales_Order" and getting error like this. Below is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonTicketRq>
            <ClientDateTime>2013-10-09T07:39:09</ClientDateTime>
            <SessionTicket>******</SessionTicket>
            <Language>English</Language>
            <AppID>****My App Id****</AppID>
            <AppVer>1</AppVer>
        </SignonTicketRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>

    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <SalesOrderAddRq requestID="1">
            <SalesOrderAdd>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <FullName>vivek patel</FullName>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TxnDate>2013-10-09</TxnDate>
                <RefNumber>23112628110</RefNumber>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>Pam  Barker</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>500 Kirts Boulevard</Addr2>
                    <Addr3/>
                    <City>Troy</City>
                    <State>Mi</State>
                    <PostalCode>48084</PostalCode>
                    <Country>US</Country>
                </BillAddress>
                <ShipAddress>
                    <Addr1/>
                    <Addr2>7322 Southwest Freeway </Addr2>
                    <Addr3>Ste, 170</Addr3>
                    <City>Houston</City>
                    <State>TX</State>
                    <PostalCode>77074</PostalCode>
                    <Country>US</Country>
                </ShipAddress>
                <ItemSalesTaxRef>
                    <FullName>Out of State</FullName>
                </ItemSalesTaxRef>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>Series 01 (20 Labels) </FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>Series 01 (20 Labels) </Desc>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Amount>9.95</Amount>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
            </SalesOrderAdd>
        </SalesOrderAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2013 13:03:51 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8r ApacheJServ/1.1.2
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC "-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBO 6.0//EN" "http://apps.quickbooks.com/dtds/qbxmlops60.dtd">
<QBXML>
 <SignonMsgsRs>
  <SignonTicketRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="INFO">
   <ServerDateTime>2013-10-09T13:03:49</ServerDateTime>
   <SessionTicket>V1-95-Q0zql4yqpal0scxpwbbcjv:816233885</SessionTicket>
  </SignonTicketRs>
 </SignonMsgsRs>
 <QBXMLMsgsRs>
  <SalesOrderAddRs requestID="1" statusCode="1030" statusMessage="Not supported" statusSeverity="Error"/>
 </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Need help for this.Is it mandatory that we must have products available before we make QBXML code for adding sales order. If so then when I am adding products with QBXML then it will give me same error like above.
I referred this URL http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml_iteminventoryadd  for products add.

Also requestID="1" is it a unique id in it ? 
and what is

```
<RefNumber>23112628110</RefNumber>
```

stands for in QBXML ? is there any references available for QBXML's attributes description.

Please provide some help for it.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> SignonDesktopRs statusCode="2000" statusMessage="Application agent
>   not found **************" statusSeverity="ERROR"

Indicates that either your App ID, App Login, Connection Ticket, or registration settings are incorrect.

What are the settings that your app is registered with? Is it registered as a PRODUCTION, QBOE app?

Comment: Yes, It is registered in PRODUCTION mode with Log in security off and QBOE app from below URL,
https://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/QBOE

Also you can see my app registration from below URL,
http://imagesup.net/?di=12138120770016

Comment: And are you sure you're using the correct connection ticket (it should be a SEPARATE connection ticket from your QBMS one) and App ID and App Login in your request?

Comment: Yes, It is separate connection ticket for my both QBMS and QBOE application.I would generated connection ticket from below URL,
https://merchantaccount.quickbooks.com/j/sdkconnection?appid=Myappid&sessionEnabled=false
My "Myappid" will replace by my QBOE app id.

Comment: That is the wrong URL. Look at that URL - it even says "merchantaccount" in it. QuickBooks Merchant Services is COMPLETELY DIFFERENT from QuickBooks Online. They are in no way related. You need to use the QBOE URL to get your QBOE connection ticket. Follow this: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Online_via_qbXML#Connecting_with_the_.27Desktop.27_model_of_communication

Comment: Thank You very much for help.I am getting right connection ticket and getting success in adding customer from website to quick book online essential account.
Please see my question now I am adding sales order, invoice and products to quick book account and find this errors.

Comment: If you have a separate question, you should generally start a separate new post, instead of editing it into something unrelated to the original question.

Comment: The reference for qbXML is here: https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html  Unfortunately, Intuit temporarily broke it last night. Sales Orders are not supported by qbXML/QuickBooks Online, hence the reason you get a "Not Supported" error message.

Comment: Thank You for your support I am succeeded in adding/updating products and customers from it.But I am unable to add an invoice. So I am creating new post for it as you suggested.
Please help me out on this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296875/qbxml-add-invoice-to-quick-book-online-essential-account-with-qboe-app-qbxml