# QBXML : Add Invoice to quick book online essential account with QBOE App /QBXML

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml

I have referenced new OSR and try to add Invoice to quick book online essential account but not getting succeeded. Please note that I have added correct list id in XML for product and customer.But It will respond me below XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonTicketRq>
            <ClientDateTime>2013-10-10T07:42:51</ClientDateTime>
            <SessionTicket>********</SessionTicket>
            <Language>English</Language>
            <AppID>**********</AppID>
            <AppVer>1</AppVer>
        </SignonTicketRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>

  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="2">
      <InvoiceAdd>
        <CustomerRef>
    <ListID>15</ListID>
          <FullName>vivek patel</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
        <TxnDate>2010-10-10</TxnDate>
        <RefNumber>1234</RefNumber>
        <BillAddress>
          <Addr1>Baroda</Addr1>
          <City>Baroda</City>
          <State>AL</State>
          <PostalCode>123456789</PostalCode>
          <Country>US</Country>
        </BillAddress>
        <PONumber></PONumber>
        <Memo></Memo>
        <InvoiceLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>
          <ListID>8</ListID>
          <FullName>Test Service</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>Test Service</Desc>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Rate>20</Rate>
        </InvoiceLineAdd>
      </InvoiceAdd>
    </InvoiceAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Oct 2013 13:05:05 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8r ApacheJServ/1.1.2
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC "-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBO 6.0//EN" "http://apps.quickbooks.com/dtds/qbxmlops60.dtd">
<QBXML>
 <SignonMsgsRs>
  <SignonTicketRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="INFO">
   <ServerDateTime>2013-10-10T13:05:07</ServerDateTime>
   <SessionTicket>*********</SessionTicket>
  </SignonTicketRs>
 </SignonMsgsRs>
 <QBXMLMsgsRs>
  <InvoiceAddRs requestID="2" statusCode="530" statusMessage="A field that is not supported was included in the request. The remainder of the request was processed normally, but the unsupported field was ignored." statusSeverity="Warning">
   <InvoiceRet>
    <TxnID>15</TxnID>
    <TimeCreated>2013-10-10T06:05:06</TimeCreated>
    <TimeModified>2013-10-10T06:05:06</TimeModified>
    <EditSequence>0</EditSequence>
    <TxnNumber>15</TxnNumber>
    <CustomerRef>
     <ListID>15</ListID>
     <FullName>vivek patel</FullName>
    </CustomerRef>
    <ARAccountRef>
     <ListID>54</ListID>
     <FullName>Accounts Receivable (A/R)</FullName>
    </ARAccountRef>
    <TxnDate>2010-10-10</TxnDate>
    <RefNumber>1234</RefNumber>
    <BillAddress>
     <Addr1>Baroda</Addr1>
     <City>Baroda</City>
     <State>AL</State>
     <PostalCode>123456789</PostalCode>
     <Country>US</Country>
    </BillAddress>
    <ShipAddress>
     <Addr1>Baroda</Addr1>
     <Addr2>Baroda2</Addr2>
     <City>Baroda3</City>
     <State>AL</State>
     <PostalCode>123456789</PostalCode>
     <Country>US</Country>
    </ShipAddress>
    <DueDate>2010-11-09</DueDate>
    <Subtotal>20.00</Subtotal>
    <SalesTaxPercentage>0</SalesTaxPercentage>
    <AppliedAmount>0.00</AppliedAmount>
    <BalanceRemaining>20.00</BalanceRemaining>
    <IsPaid>false</IsPaid>
    <IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted>
    <InvoiceLineRet>
     <TxnLineID>1</TxnLineID>
     <ItemRef>
      <ListID>8</ListID>
      <FullName>Test Service vivek</FullName>
     </ItemRef>
     <Desc>Test Service vivek</Desc>
     <Quantity>1</Quantity>
     <Rate>20</Rate>
     <Amount>20.00</Amount>
     <IsTaxable>false</IsTaxable>
    </InvoiceLineRet>
   </InvoiceRet>
  </InvoiceAddRs>
 </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 3):

This response message:

```
<InvoiceAddRs requestID="2" statusCode="530" statusMessage="A field that is not supported was included in the request. The remainder of the request was processed normally, but the unsupported field was ignored." statusSeverity="Warning">
```

Means pretty much exactly what it says it means.

The request *was* successful - your invoice was added successfully.

*However*, you should be aware (hence the warning) that you used a field that wasn't supported by QuickBooks Online edition. If you look in the OSR (make sure to check the OE checkbox, uncheck the US checkbox, and set to 6.0 for QuickBooks Online), you'll notice that QuickBooks Online does *not* support this field:

- PONumber

Thus, it's telling you that the field is unsupported.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.It is successfully done.
But It will add invoice with No payment received in our online quick book account. Is there any attributes in "InvoiceAdd" OR any other method to make that invoice like payment is received ?

Comment: Just like in the QuickBooks GUI, a payment is a *completely separate transaction* in the QuickBooks API. If you want to add an invoice, you do an InvoiceAdd. If you want to add a received payment, you do a ReceivePaymentAdd.

Comment: Thank You, very much for the help.I am succeeded in push data from website to quick book.